# Resize url image using urllib and pil

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, python-imaging-library, urllib

I am looking to retrieve an image from a url, resize it (to fit appropriately in the GUI), and then display the image in the GUI. I believe I have the basic premise down...or at least I know how to retrieve and display an image. I have provided some sample code below.

```
import pywapi, pprint, string, urllib, io
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1440x900+0+0")
fd = urllib.urlopen("http://images.intellicast.com/WxImages/Radar/den.gif")
imgFile = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgFile)) # <-- here
image = Label(root, image = im, bd =2)
image.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 30)

# This is just some working code for resizing an image from a url
#fd = urllib.urlretrieve("http://images.intellicast.com/WxImages/Radar/den.gif", "den.gif")
#im1 = Image.open("den.gif")    
#im_small = im1.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
#im_small.save("den.gif")

root.mainloop()
```

So both code sections work, I am just unsure of how to combine them appropriately. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `im_small` to `PhotoImage` instead of `Image.open`.

```
fd = urllib.urlretrieve("http://images.intellicast.com/WxImages/Radar/den.gif", "den.gif")
im1 = Image.open("den.gif")    
im_small = im1.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_small)
image = Label(root, image = im, bd =2)
image.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 30)
```